# kubelet reading from wrong config file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet

When I run `kubelet version` I get an error message ending in:

`error: failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: misconfiguration: kubelet cgroup driver: "cgroupfs" is different from docker cgroup driver: "systemd"`

But when I check the config file located at `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`, I see the value IS systemd. I have changed the value and done a `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart kubelet` in between each change and the error message is always the same.

I am guessing it must be reading from the wrong config file, but how can I find where it is reading from!

Comment: What is the kubelet version?

Comment: and the output from `systemctl cat kubelet.service` (as it may be pulling in yet another drop-in)? Plus, don't overlook the value of `kubelet --v=100` to show _exactly_ what's going on

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
kubelet  --cgroup-driver=systemd version
```

The "docker" package (1.13.1) already has "systemd" as the default cgroup-driver, see [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4770#issuecomment-517936983).

The file driver is `systemd` changed by default `cgroupfs`, and docker file driver we installed is `systemd` caused by inconsistency, which causes the image to fail to start.

```
     docker info 

...
     Cgroup Driver: systemd
```

There are two ways now, one is to modify docker, the other is to modify kubelet,

Modify docker: #
Modify or create `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add the following:

```
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
}
```

Restart docker:

```
systemctl restart docker
systemctl status docker
```

Modify kubelet: #

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

```
# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

Add the following content `--cgroup-driver=systemd` to $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS.

Or:

```
$ DOCKER_CGROUPS=$(docker info | grep 'Cgroup' | cut -d' ' -f3)
$ echo $DOCKER_CGROUPS

$ cat >/etc/sysconfig/kubelet<<EOF
KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS="--cgroup-driver=$DOCKER_CGROUPS"
EOF

#restart
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl restart kubelet
```

Or:

```
DOCKER_CGROUPS=$(docker info | grep 'Cgroup' | cut -d' ' -f3)
echo $DOCKER_CGROUPS
cat >/etc/sysconfig/kubelet<<EOF
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS="--cgroup-driver=$DOCKER_CGROUPS"
EOF

# restart
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl enable kubelet && systemctl restart kubelet
```